# How do we find first order estimate of the given entropy of the following image

Tags: image-processing

[image]

What is the solution for this answer? Should we use log base 2 in the formula?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the pixels of images as the realization of a discrete random variable on sample space $\Omega = \{0, 1, \ldots, 255\}$ and probability mass function $p \colon \Omega \in [0,1]$ defined as:
$$
p(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{5}{16} & \text{if } x = 200 \text{ or } x = 210,\\
\frac{3}{16} & \text{if } x = 215 \text{ or } x = 217,\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
By applying the [Shannon's definition of entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) we obtain:
$$
\begin{align}
H(X) &= -\sum_{i=0}^{255} p(i)\cdot \log_b(p(i))\\
&= -\frac{5}{16}\log_b\left(\frac{5}{16}\right)-\frac{5}{16}\log_b\left(\frac{5}{16}\right)-\frac{3}{16}\log_b\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)-\frac{3}{16}\log_b\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)\\
&= -\frac{1}{8}\left(5\log_b\left(\frac{5}{16}\right)-3\log_b\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)\right)\\
&= -\frac{1}{8}\left(\log_b\left(\frac{5^5}{16^5}\frac{3^3}{16^3}\right)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{8}\left(\log_b\left(\frac{16^8}{5^5 3^3}\right)\right)\\
&= \log_b\left(\frac{16}{\sqrt[8]{5^5 3^3}}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
The choice of the value for the basis $b$ of logarithm depends on the units in which you want to express the result:

- base $2$: $ H(X) \approx 1.954$ bits,
- base $e$: $ H(X) \approx 1.355$ nats,
- base $3$: $ H(X) \approx 1.233$ trits,
- base $10$: $ H(X) \approx 0.588$ dits.